# Multidimensional array of INT in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, int

I've created a simple program that use a multidimensional array of INT in c.

He is designed in a structure :

```
typedef struct s_control
{
    int rangees;
    int **rangees_content;
} t_control;
```

Then, I malloc the struct etc...
But, when I try to edit a case like that :

```
opt->rangees_content[line] = tmp;
```

Where "tmp" is an int declared by "`int tmp;`"

Then I compile and got :

> ./main.c:9:30: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast [enabled by default]    opt->rangees_content[line] =
>   tmp;

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you `malloc()`ing the `rangees_content`? And please define **multidimensional**, is it just **bi-dimensional**?

Comment: `rangees_content[line]` is an `int*`. You can't assign an `int` to that.

Comment: Array isn't malloced. Yep, only "bi-dimensional", sorry

Comment: rangees_content[line] sounds like you want to assign an entire row, so you should be assigning an int [], not an int.

Comment: And so ? What 'im supposed to do ?

Comment: There's simply no way to assign an array as a whole. You'll have to use a loop.

Comment: @cmaster `memcpy()`? assignment certainly is not possible, but in the c language you can use `memcpy()`.

Comment: @iharob And what is `memcpy()` internally? It's just some odd library function that happens to be included in the standard library so that you don't need to add a `-l` flag for it. It's written in C itself, and guess what it contains...

Comment: @cmaster that's why I said `in the c lagnauge`. It's not written in c, at all. Have you checked the source code of `glibc` for example?

Comment: @iharob I don't have the time to look into the `glibc` source code today, do they actually employ assembler code? That's possible, of course, but only a means of optimization. `memcpy()` can be implemented in C no problem. And even the assembler version will contain a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign an integer to an `int` pointer, that shouldn't be done, it causes undefined behavior when trying to dereference the pointer.

In other words, a `int **` means that it can be accessed like a 2-dimensional array, you are accessing one of it dimensions which has type `int *` and trying to assing an `int` to it.

This is an example of how to use an `int **` pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct s_control
{
    size_t rangees;
    int **rangees_content;
} t_control;

int
main()
{
    t_control control;
    size_t    rowSize;
    /* this is irrelevant to your problem, just initialize the random seed */
    srand(time(NULL));
    /* Initialize the struct members */
    control.rangees         = 10;
    control.rangees_content = malloc(control.rangees * sizeof(int *));
    /*                                                        ^ 
     * Above, you allocate 'control.rangees' pointers of 'int'
     */
    if (control.rangees_content == NULL)
        return -1;
    rowSize = 10; /* this value can be changed */
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < control.rangees ; ++i)
    {
        /* this is the i-th row of the array and has type 'int *', malloc it */
        control.rangees_content[i] = malloc(rowSize * sizeof(int));
        if (control.rangees_content[i] == NULL)
        {
            /* always handle malloc failure */
            while (i >= 0)
                free(control.rangees_content[i--]);
            free(control.rangees_content);

            return -1;
        }
        /* Iterate through the array elements, and assign random values to them */
        for (size_t j = 0 ; j < rowSize ; ++j)
            control.rangees_content[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }
    /* print and free the array */
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < control.rangees ; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0 ; j < rowSize ; ++j)
            printf("%5d", control.rangees_content[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
        free(control.rangees_content[i]);
    }
    free(control.rangees_content);
    return 0;
}
```

the above program, generates random numbers and fills the array with them, and then outputs them to `stdout`.

Comment: It should be noted that the array create as shown is a "*scattered*" array. It is not represented by a continous block of memory, but by `1 + rowSize ` seperate blocks